# How to create files with names from a file and then writing to files? Python. API request

Tags: python, api, csv, writetofile, get-request

There is an algorithm in the end of the text. It reads lines from the file **SP500.txt**. File contains strings and it looks like:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Substitutes these strings in the get request and saves the entire url to a file **url_requests.txt**. For the example:

```
https://apidate.com/api/api/AAA.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d
https://apidate.com/api/api/BBB.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d
https://apidate.com/api/api/CCC.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d
```

and then processes each request via the API and adds all responses to get requests to **responses.txt**.
I don't know how to save the response from each request from the file **url_requests.txt** into separate csv file instead of **responses.txt** (now they are all written to this file, and not separately). In this case, it is important to name each file with the corresponding line from the file **SP500.txt**. For example:

```
AAA.csv `(which contains data from the request response https://apidate.com/api/api/AAA.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d)`
BBB.csv `(which contains data from the request response https://apidate.com/api/api/BBB.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d)`
CCC.csv `(which contains data from the request response https://apidate.com/api/api/CCC.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d)`
```

So, algorithm is:

```
import requests

        # to use strip to remove spaces in textfiles.
import sys

        # two variables to squeeze a string between these two so it will become a full uri
part1 = 'https://apidate.com/api/api/'
part2 = '.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d'

        # open the outputfile before the for loop
text_file = open("url_requests.txt", "w")

        # open the file which contains the strings
with open('SP500.txt', 'r') as f:
              for i in f:
                uri = part1 + i.strip(' \n\t') + part2
                print(uri)
                text_file.write(uri)
                text_file.write("\n")

text_file.close()

        # open a new file textfile for saving the responses from the api
text_file = open("responses.txt", "w")

        # send every uri to the api and write the respones to a textfile
with open('url_requests.txt', 'r') as f2:
            for i in f2:
                uri = i.strip(' \n\t')
                batch = requests.get(i)
                data = batch.text
                print(data)
                text_file.write(data)
                text_file.write('\n')

text_file.close()
```

And I know how to save csv from this response. It is like:

```
import csv
import requests

url = "https://apidate.com/api/api/AAA.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d"
response = requests.get(url)

with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in response.iter_lines():
        writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: and what is the problem? do you get error message? always put full error message (startingat word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot).There are other useful infrmation.

Comment: maybe better read data from `SP500.txt` and keep in memory all time as a list or dictionary. And then you may create pairs line `["AAA", 'https://...AAA...']` and use it to get data for `https://...AAA...` and save in `AAA.csv` OR keep `"AAA", 'https://...AAA...'` in `'url_requests.txt'`

Comment: btw; If you use `strip()` without argument then it will use `' \n\t'`

Comment: to save in different files you have to use `open(f"{name}.csv", "w")` inside `for`-loop.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Code is working perfect. But all responses are saved in a single file responses.txt now, so I want to save them separate: response from one request save to one file, response from another request save to the second file and etc.

Comment: @furas I have not got an error message. Just don't know what I have to do to save each response in separate file (csv) and give these files names according to the strings inside SP500.txt file

Comment: to save in separted file you have to do it inside `for`-loop when you get data for separated url. ANd you have to use ie. `open(name + ".csv", "w")` to use different name. And it would be easier to keep all names on list - first use `for`-loop to read all names from file and keep on list. And later use this list to create url and to save in file

Comment: or maybe you should put some code in functions and then would be easier to use `save(name, data)` inside `for`-loop.

Comment: you could also learn string formattion or `f-string` and you wouldn't have to keep url as `part1`, `part2`

Comment: @furas But don't I need to do it in the latest 'for-' loop? So far, I do not fully understand how to do this, although your idea is clear and logical. MAybe I don't have enough skill to apply it.

Comment: you have to do it inside last `for`-loop but if you would have names and urls on list then you could use loop `for name, url in zip(all_names, all_urls):` without reading from file, and then you could use `url` to read data, and after `requests.get` you could use `open(name)` and `write()` to save data in file with unique filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save in different names you have to use `open()` and `write()` inside `for`-loop when you read data.

It would good to read all names to list and later generate urls and also keep on list so you would not have to read them.

When I see code which you use to save `csv` then it looks like you get `csv` from server so you could save all at once using `open()` `write()` without `csv` module.

I see it in this way.

```
import requests
#import csv

# --- read names ---

all_names = []  # to keep all names in memory

with open('SP500.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        line = line.strip()
        print('name:', name)
        all_names.append(line)

# ---- generate urls ---

url_template = 'https://apidate.com/api/api/{}.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d'

all_uls = []  # to keep all urls in memory

with open("url_requests.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for name in all_names:
        url = url_template.format(name)
        print('url:', url)
        all_uls.append(url)
        text_file.write(url + "\n")

# --- read data ---

for name, url in zip(all_names, all_urls):
    #print('name:', name)
    #print('url:', url)
    
    response = requests.get(url)

    with open(name + '.csv', 'w') as text_file:
        text_file.write(response.text)
        
        #writer = csv.writer(text_file)
        #for line in response.iter_lines():
        #    writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(',')
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working great. Infinitely grateful. It is really better then mine code.

Comment: I didn't describe all elements - like [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate a filename for every string i, and open (create) a file each time.

Something like this:

```
import sys
import requests
# two variables to squeeze a string between these two so it will become a full uri
part1 = 'https://apidate.com/api/api/'
part2 = '.US?api_token=XXXXXXXX&period=d'
# open the outputfile before the for loop
text_file = open("url_requests.txt", "w")
uri_dict = {}
with open('SP500.txt', 'r') as f:
   for i in f:
     uri = part1 + i.strip(' \n\t') + part2
     print(uri)
     text_file.write(uri)
     text_file.write("\n")
     uri_dict[i] = uri
text_file.close()
for symbol, uri in uri_dict:
    batch = requests.get(uri)
    data = batch.text
    print(data)
    #create the filename
    filename = symbol+".csv"
    #open (create) the file and save the data
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(data)
        f.write('\n')
```

You could also get rid of url_requests.csv, which becomes useless (until you have other uses for it).